# Web Audio analyser returns zeros when using createMediaElementSource

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, audio-analysis

I am trying to analyse a live audio stream from a url.

I have tested my code with mic input and it works well however when I change

```
createMediaStreamSource(micStream)
```

To

```
var streamURL = new Audio(['http://urlOnRemoteServer'])
createMediaStreamSource(streamURL)
```

Then getByteFrequencyData just returns arrays of zeros (with mic input it returns real data instead of zeros).

It looks like firefox has a Same-origin policy so I moved my code to a web server and used a temporary audio file, however this produces the same results on both Firefox and Chrome so I assume this isn't to do with browser support...

Example JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j68fhz9x/

I am using Firefox/Chrome on Debian Linux

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

After looking into CORS I instead tried to run the app locally, however the problem persists even if I have both the script and audio file on a local computer.

Comment: What happens when you connect the source to the master output? Do you hear any sound?

Comment: Also, could you provide a fiddle or similar?

Comment: Fiddle now included in answer

Comment: So in my enviroment (Manjaro Linux/FF 38), when I open the linked audio stream directly, it does not work either. You should try with a test file.

Comment: Yes the stream seems to be glitching a bit at the moment, I have replaced it with a test file

Comment: If  by running locally means you load the files through file:// then this is also considered being different origin. You need to set up a server (or use an IDE like WebStorm, VIsual Studio with a built-in server) and run from localhost/127.0.0.1

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a same origin file or CORS, for Firefox and chrome.

Comment: I really wish browser vendors would do the same the same thing they do with XHRs and output some error/warning to the console so at least the developer has some hint as to why their audio is silent and how to fix it.

Comment: Well, at least in Chrome 45 it now outputs the following to the console when you run into this issue now: "MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for `AUDIO_URL`" However Firefox 40 still provides nothing helpful in the console.

Comment: I have had a look at making CORS requests but how can I make one if the url is passed as a string parameter? eg new Audio(["cors_url_request"])

Comment: Try streamURL.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'